# Apache has to be restarted dozens of times before Python responds

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a strange issue, if I restart Apache with my DJANGO Application then static files respond just fine (like the Apache Status Page shows it is handling requests). There are no errors in the log files, and WSGI loads as far as the logfile is concerned.

The problem is that my DJANGO/Python/WSGI Application is not responding to any requests, the web page just times out.  I have to restart Apache over and over again, sometimes for up to an hour before the application finally responds. The strange part is that sometimes it will restart immediately. Nothing helps, boot order has no affect, restarting the entire server has not helped. I chased down linked libraries and cleared out the duplicate loading from other requests that I have seen.

**A few environment items:**

- Windows Server Apache 2.2
- Python 2.6
- Django 1.4.5
- MOD_WSGI 3.5 for Windows Apache (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi)

**One last detail:**

If I block HTTP and HTTPS ports using the firewall and restart Apache then enable the firewall then the service comes right up. So there seams to be some problem with active sessions and Apache/WSGI/Pyhton/Django.

Any ideas on what I can tweak in my WSGI or Apache configuration to get the application to come right up?

Comment: How do you test if it's responding or not? Have you tried testing accessing localhost from command-line, bypassing the browsers, firewalls and other factors which may cause interference.

Comment: Great question, I can access any static files. I can also access the Apache status page that I have enabled. I have tried localhost, domain name, telnet session (local and remote), direct IP address and more. It feels like Python is hanging on a thread that it wants to process before the system is ready, but not one exception or error is logged or displayed anywhere.

Comment: If it's possible I suggest try alternative solution for mod_wsgi, like uWSGI. The major benefit is that uWSGI has thread dump capability, so you know exactly where you application is hanging. No guesswork needed.

Comment: Not sure if you can do that with Apache 2.2. Native thread dumping capability didn't arrive to Python until v3.4, but uWSGI can do it also for Py 2.

Comment: Hmm... also the factor that you run on Windows complicates the matter... all debugging capabilities might not be available on this platform.

Comment: Agreed, not supportive of the environment, but its one of those scenarios where you just have to use what you have (a really long story). We are working on porting to Linux and that is a long haul.  I have thought about uWSGI, might be worth taking a crack at it.